# Application Insights -_logger.LogInformation

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

I have created a very simple asp.net core application to learn more about Azure Application Insights

I can log LogWarning, LogError and LogCritical messages to my Azure Application Insights which I see when I query "traces" table under logs. The issue I am having for LogDebug, LogInformation and LogTrace I cannot find the messages

Below is some related code/config:

```
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();



// Example log level configuration in Startup.cs

builder.Services.AddLogging(builder => builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));



"Logging": {

"LogLevel": {

"Default": "Information",

//Only the WARNING messages for HttpClient will be logged

"System.Net.Http.HttpClient": "Warning"

}

}
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The issue I am having for LogDebug, LogInformation and LogTrace I cannot find the messages

I have created simple dotnet core web application with .net version 6.0 in visual studio.
I was configure application insights in the application by using appinsights connection string.

**.cs proj:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" Version="2.22.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**program.cs:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
//var abc = builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"];
var app = builder.Build();
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

**appsettings.json:**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "Your-application insights-connection string"
  }
}
```

**HomeController.cs:**

```
using appinsightweb.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace appinsightweb.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("This is an Information log.");
            _logger.LogWarning("This is a Warning log.");
            _logger.LogError("This is an Error log.");
            _logger.LogCritical("This is a Critical log.");

            // For Debug and Trace logs, ensure that the log level is configured appropriately in Startup.cs

            _logger.LogDebug("This is a Debug log.");
            _logger.LogTrace("This is a Trace log.");
            return View();
        }
```

By using above code and configuration able to get the different type of logs in application insights. Check below:

[image]